# Discounted cumulated gain

Tags: ranking, information-retrieval

I've a little question regarding the Discounted Cumulated Gain (DCG) (Sorry, I couldn't find the papers of Järvelin and Kekäläinen). Can this evaluation-metric be used when a information retrieval system has only a binary classification of relevance? If this topic is misplaced, please tell where I should post it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it can. Using the standard logarithmic discount it then allows you to conclude - for instance - that a search result with relevances 0,1,1 and 0 is slightly better than a search result with relevances 1,0,0 and 1.

As a side note, note that the logarithmic discount is not motivated by theory; it is merely used out of convenience and with other discounts your ranking of the results will differ. It may be worth while to think and pick a scheme that captures what it actually is you want to optimise.